# Threads not being properly synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I'm trying to create a class that calculates the total area and perimeter for 5 different shapes, but each area and perimeter for a given shape is calculated by a separate thread. So far I can't get the threads to sync properly so the totalArea and totalPerimeter are calculated properly. Any advice to get the threads to work? The totalArea and totalPerimeter for the code below should be equal to 610.829 for the area and 187.115 for the perimeter if I don't calculate each shape with a thread. If I do the values become something completely random.

```
package PartB;

import PartA.Step2.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;



public class Picture implements Runnable{
    public List<Shape> picture;
    public Shape selectedShape;
    public ListIterator<Shape> e;
    double totalArea;
    double totalPerimeter;
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double length;
    double width;
    double height;
    double radius;


    public Picture(double a, double b, double c, double length, double width, double height, double radius){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
        Shape[] shapes = {new Circle(radius), new Square(length),
                new Rectangle(length, width), new Parallelogram(length, width, height),
                new Triangle(a, b, c)};
        picture = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(shapes));

    }

    public double getTotalArea(){return totalArea;}

    public double getTotalPerimeter(){return totalPerimeter;}


    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (this) {
        totalArea += selectedShape.getArea();
        totalPerimeter += selectedShape.getPerimeter();
        System.out.println(totalArea);
        System.out.println(totalPerimeter);
    }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Picture pictures = new Picture(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
        for(pictures.e = pictures.picture.listIterator(); pictures.e.hasNext();){
            pictures.selectedShape = pictures.e.next();
            new Thread(pictures).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Shape interface:

```
package PartA.Step2;

public interface Shape {
    double getPerimeter();
    double getArea();
}
```

One of the sub-classes of shape:

```
package PartA.Step2;

public class Circle implements Shape, Cloneable {
    double radius;


    public Circle(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        CalculateShape calc = (radius)->Math.PI * Math.pow(radius[0], 2);
        return calc.process(radius);

    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        CalculateShape calc = (radius)->2 * Math.PI * radius[0];
        return calc.process(radius);

    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Area: " + getArea() +
                "\nPerimeter : " + getPerimeter();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Circle){
            if(((Circle) obj).radius == radius)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no synchronization whatsoever in the code you have posted...

Comment: Its not very clear to me what you want? What do these threads do? Why do you want the synchronized? And in what order do you want to run them?

Comment: @Necreaux Check again

Comment: Because you're not synchronizing on the same object?

Comment: @Cheiron I want each thread to calculate the total area and total perimeter for a Shape in Picture. Since there are 5 different shapes, 5 threads are made, with each calculating the total area and total perimeter for a given shape and adding those values to the total area and perimeter for the Picture.

Comment: Also you would need to wait until all shapes are created first... I suggest you get a book about multi-threading, you're far away from your goal.

Comment: Ok, I see the unindented synchronized block inside Picture.run() now. I'm not sure that actually does anything.

Comment: @onemic synchronized(this) will not do anything since you have a set amount of objects, each with their own "this". So you are basically saying that each object can only have its "run" function run once at a time. But your main function only lets each objects' run function run once, so the synchronized block will not do anything. Why specifically are you multithreading here? The multithread overhead seems to be a lot more then the time it would take to make the calculations.

Comment: There is no point of it being multithreaded really. The only reason why I'm doing it is because its a requirement for my assignment to use a thread.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot there was a way to make the main thread wait until a thread was no longer alive. By doing that I was able to make each thread calculate a shapes area and perimeter without interference from other threads. There was no point of the synchronized part as @cheiron said:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        Picture pictures = new Picture(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
        for(pictures.e = pictures.picture.listIterator(); pictures.e.hasNext();){
            pictures.selectedShape = pictures.e.next();
            Thread thread = new Thread(pictures);
            thread.start();
            while(thread.isAlive()){
                try {
                    thread.join();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I now get the correct total area and total perimeter for the entire picture.